# Show that if $z_1+z_2$ and $z_1\overline{z_2}$ are both real $(z_2 \neq0)$ then either $z_1$ and $z_2 $ are both real or $z_1=-z_2$

Tags: complex-analysis

Show that if $z_1+z_2$ and $z_1\overline{z_2}$ are both real $(z_2 \neq0)$  then either $z_1$ and $z_2 $ are both real or $z_1=-z_2$

**my attmept:**

since $z_1+z_2$  is real and  $z_1+z_2=(a_1+a_2+i(b_1+b_2)$

and imaginary part must be zero then $b_1+b_2=0$

Also $z_1\overline{z_2}$ real then $a_1+a_2=0$

this comes $z_1=-z_2$

how to prove either $z_1$ and $z_2 $ are both real

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $$b_1+b_2=0\iff b_2=-b_1$$

and $$z_1\bar{z_2}=(a_1+ib_1)(a_2-ib_2)=(a_1+ib_1)(a_2+ib_1)=\cdots+ib_1(a_1+a_2)$$

If $b_1=0,b_2=0\implies z_1,z_2$ are real

else $a_2=-a_1$

So, $z_2=a_2+ib_2=-(a_1+ib_1)$

Answer (score 1):

$z_1 \overline{z_2} \in \mathbb{R} \Rightarrow \displaystyle \frac{z_1}{z_2} |z_2|^2 \in \mathbb{R} \Rightarrow \displaystyle \frac{z_1}{z_2} \in \mathbb{R} $

$\Rightarrow \displaystyle \frac{z_1+z_2}{z_2} \in \mathbb{R}$ (adding $1$)

Now either $z_1+z_2 = 0$ or $z_2 \in \mathbb{R}$ from which it immediately follows $z_1 \in \mathbb{R}$